# Add new languages to enchant on Mac OS

Tags: macos, python-2.7, pyenchant

I try to add a new language to pyenchant in the anaconda package on Mac OS. I downloaded the files for myspell (ru_RU.aff and ru_RU.dic).
As I understand, I have to add these files to the */user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/enchant/share/myspell/*

Well, there is no directory *share* in the */user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/enchant/*, so I created the folder */user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/enchant/share/myspell/* and added the files... So, it doesn't work.

How can I really add the new language to enchant?

Comment: what happens if you run (as three lines) from a python prompt: b = enchant.Broker() b.describe() b.list_dicts()

Comment: >>> b.describe()
[<Enchant: Aspell Provider>]
>>> b.list_dicts()
[('en', <Enchant: Aspell Provider>), ('en_CA', <Enchant: Aspell Provider>), ('en_GB', <Enchant: Aspell Provider>), ('en_US', <Enchant: Aspell Provider>)]

Comment: Try (as four lines): enchant.set_param("enchant.myspell.dictionary.path","/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/enchant/share/myspell/") b = enchant.Broker() b.describe() b.list_dicts()

Comment: The result is the same